# Python file read and save

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used Python 3.6 version and now I want to save name & age at the file and then read the text as name + tab + age but I can't approach file read side.

My code:

```
while True:
    print("-------------")
    name=input("Name: ")
    age=input ("Age: ")
    contInput=input("Continue Input? (y/n) ")
    fp.open("test.txt", "a")
    fp.write(name+","+age+"\n")
    if contInput=="n":
        fp.close()
        break
    else:
        continue
with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
    rd = fp.read().split('\n')
    ????
fp.close()
```

so I just confuse about file read. I want to print my saved data like below.

name [tab] age

but after used split method, rd type is list. 
Can I divide name & age as each items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fp.open("test.txt", "a")
```

At this point in your program, `fp` doesn't exist yet.  Perhaps you meant `fp = open(...)` instead?

You're only closing the file if the user chose not to continue, but you're opening it every time through the loop.  You should open and close it only once, or open *and* close it every time through the loop.

```
fp.write(name+","+"age"+"\n")
```

This writes the literal word `age` instead of the age variable.  You probably wanted this instead: `fp.write(name + "," + age + "\n")`

Try this for your input loop:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        data = line.split(",")
        name = data[0]
        age = data[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is very useful to me. :)